# Is there a difference between `requirejs` and `require` to set RequireJS' configuration?

Tags: requirejs

I've found many examples where config set in this way:

> require.config({
>       'path':{'':''}
>   })

and many examples where config set in this way:

> requirejs.config({
>       'path':{'':''}
>   })

Which is right? When must one use one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

In general, both are correct. RequireJS defines `require` and `requirejs` as global symbols. The two symbols are equivalent.

However, if something has already defined a global function named `require` before RequireJS is loaded, then RequireJS will leave it alone and will only define itself as `requirejs`. **In this case**, you cannot use `require` to do anything with RequireJS. You have to use `requirejs` instead.

(However the option name is `paths`, not `path`. You have `path` in your question.)